# Execute csproj file with argument

Tags: msbuild, csproj

I need to execute 1 csproj from my solution use MsBuild with command line argument.

I created the file with MsBuild run command:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="14.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2002">
<PropertyGroup>
    <Version>1.2.0</Version>    
</PropertyGroup>
    <Target Name="Build" >
        <MSBuild Projects="$(ProjectFolder)\Proj1.csproj" Properties="Configuration=Release" />     
    </Target>
</Project>
```

And I added into proj1.csproj file the following attribute:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="14.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2002">
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>    
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
    <StartArguments>TestArg1</StartArguments>
  </PropertyGroup>  
</Project>
```

And exeute the build. But in my app I can't see the argument

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($@"Test - {args[0]} - end");
        }
    }
```

In Console I see the:

```
"Test -   - end"
```

What I do wrong?

Comment: Have you tried adding the argument to the .csproj.user file?  I believe the arguments are a user setting.

Comment: how do you "run" the project? using visual studio or an msbuild invocation?

Comment: @MartinUllrich use msbuild invocation

Comment: @Web thx, it does not work